# drool validations for list of objects

Tags: java, drools

I have a list of pojo class objects containing 44 fields. Now i am Iterating the each object in java and passing it to the drool for validation. Is there any way to validate the entire list in drools. Sample code is

```
rule "RuleSerialNoContent"
when
    droolRecord : DroolRecordBO(flowStatus==droolRecord.FLOW_PASS,
                               serialNo.trim() not matches "^\\d{1,10}$" )
then
    droolRecord.setRuleStatus(droolRecord.SERIAL_CONTENT_ERR+
                              " "+droolRecord.getSerialNo());
    droolRecord.setFlowStatus(droolRecord.FLOW_ERROR);
    update(droolRecord);
end


rule "RuleInstitutionIdLength"
when
    droolRecord : DroolRecordBO(flowStatus==droolRecord.FLOW_PASS,
                                institutionId.length() != 6 )
then
    droolRecord.setRuleStatus(droolRecord.INSTITUTIONID_LENGTH_ERR);
    droolRecord.setFlowStatus(droolRecord.FLOW_ERROR);
    update(droolRecord);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Insert the `List<DroolRecordBO>` and add a "from" clause to all rules:

```
rule "RuleSerialNoContent"
when
$list: List()
droolRecord : DroolRecordBO(flowStatus==droolRecord.FLOW_PASS,
                           serialNo.trim() not matches "^\\d{1,10}$" )
              from $list
then...
```

You can omit the update since the list elements won't be facts any more.

However, take care: some rule combinations you may have cannot be adjusted for this subtly changed scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to perform operation on list of objects. Advantage is that you don't have to bear the pain of compilation time for each object instead you will compile it one time only.

```
public static KnowledgeBase getKBase(String filePath) {

    KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
    kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newFileResource(filePath), ResourceType.DRL);
    KnowledgeBase kbase = kbuilder.newKnowledgeBase();
    kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Collection<DroolRecordBO> droolRecordBOs = // Collection of DroolRecordBO
    KnowledgeBase kbase = getKBase(".drl File Path");
    StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();

    for(DroolRecordBO droolRecordBO : droolRecordBOs) {
        ksession.insert(droolRecordBO);
    }
    ksession.fireAllRules();
    ksession.dispose();
}
```

If you want the rules to be executed in a specific order, you might have to consider using `salience`